# How to test CheckPhoneNumber verification API in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I follow [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Create+and+Publish+an+API)

I created API for CheckPhoneNumber 'POST' and 'GET' type request as given documentation.

How to test that API?

I searched many sites they are using  'API Console' tab in store. There is required Access Token. I am creating Access 'Production Keys' from DefaultApplication. that Access token am using it is giving error

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security">
<ams:code>900908</ams:code>
<ams:message>Resource forbidden </ams:message>
<ams:description>Access failure for API: /phoneverify/1.0.0, version: 1.0.0 status: (900908) - Resource forbidden </ams:description>
</ams:fault>
```

If there is another way to create Access Token?

Or tell me if am doing something wrong for testing API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe the Application to the API.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Subscribe+to+an+API

Answer (score -1):

As @Bee pointed out above, you don't have issues with access token, the problem is you have not subscribed to your api in the api manager. error code 900908 implies the API is not subscribed to by the app trying to invoke it.